# Is there a closed form solution for KL between multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am able to find a closed form solution for univariate Gaussian.
However, I am wondering that is there a closed form solution for high-dimensional Gaussian ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Look at the following [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Kullback.E2.80.93Leibler_divergence).